# Flagging a comment on a grayed-out answer is acting weird

Tags: bug, comments, design, comment-flags

When flagging a comment on an answer scored -3 or lower (so it's grayed out), if you move your mouse off of the answer/flag dialog the flag dialog grays out as well and hides under things.

[image: Puzzling.SE]

In this example on Puzzling.SE, the bottom of the flag dialog snuck under the spoiler on the answer below. It's a little more drastic when the answer is at the bottom, though, such as in this example on Scifi.SE:

[image: Scifi.SE]

In this case, the flag dialog hides under the place where you write your own answer.

I assume this is not intended behavior.

Comment: z-index strikes again ...